# Http status code is undefined when trying to perform a POST Sync AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, http-post

This is a javascript problem involving a post request in sync mode.

## The problem

### The code

I have the following javascript functions:

```
/**
 * Used to connect async to a server and send data using POST HTTP.
 */
function sendDataOverHttpPost(data, url, func, errfunc) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("POST", url, true);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
  http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      func(http.responseText);
    } else {
      errfunc({"name": "XMLHttpRequest error", "message": "Could not perform activity", "code": http.status, "line": "", "expressionBeginOffset": "", "expressionEndOffset": "", "sourceId": "", "sourceURL": ""});
    }
  };

  http.send(data);
}

/**
 * Used to connect sync to a server and send data using POST HTTP.
 */
function sendDataOverHttpPostSync(data, url, func, errfunc) {
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("POST", url, false);
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
  http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  http.send(data);

  /* Res handling */
    if (http.status == 200) {
      func(http.responseText);
    } else {
      errfunc({"name": "XMLHttpRequest SYNC error", "message": "Could not perform activity", "code": http.status, "line": "", "expressionBeginOffset": "", "expressionEndOffset": "", "sourceId": "", "sourceURL": ""});
    }
  /* Res handling end */
}
```

### The question

Well.
When calling the first function, the async one, everything is ok.
The problem is the second (SYNC). After sending data I always get `undefined` in `http.status`

### Possible problems

Why does this happens?
Is it a problem of headers set, because I know that when performing post queries, it is necessary to provide correct headers (this was a problem I encountered in ASYNC POST, if the headers I specified in code were missing, the response would fail).

Please consider, however, that the address is correctly called and server side, everything goes well, so the ajax request is correctly processed.

Thankyou

Comment: Shouldn't you still be checking http.status in http.onreadystatechange while in synchronous case ?

Comment: Yes, I should, I just wanted to focus on the status property.. however, readyState is 4.

Comment: What browser are you using? This fiddle works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Le265/.

Comment: Try different naming conventions for http objects in the two functions. !! Not sure that would be the problem!!

Comment: FireFox 5.0 is the browser i'm using...

Comment: I am using this on Android... Ever possible? A problem in WebKit???